# Expectation with a variable that satisfies uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, expectation

Do we have step by step proof for this expression which is concerned with the expectation of an exponential function with a variable (R) that satisfies uniform distribution. I have been trying to understand how it was derived but its seems obscure to me up till now:

$\frac{\lambda_1}{2}E_R (e^{-B_{1}R^2})E_R (e^{-D_{1}R^2}) = \\ \frac{\lambda_1 \pi}{2\sqrt{B_{1}D_{1}}(R_{max}-R_{min})^2}[\phi (2\sqrt{B_{1}}R_{max})-\phi (2\sqrt{B_{1}}R_{min})][\phi (2\sqrt{D_{1}}R_{max})-\phi (2\sqrt{D_{1}}R_{min})]$

Where $\phi$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution

R satisfies uniform distribution in $ [R_{min}, R_{max}]$ $(0\leq R_{min} < R_{max})$

Comment: What is $\lambda_1$?

Comment: @r.e.s.Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question. $\lambda_1$ is a constant which stands for density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the general form of the following expectation, where $R$ has a uniform probability density funcion $f$ on the interval $(a,b)$:
$$\begin{align}E[e^{-c\,R^2}]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c\,r^2}\,f(r)\,dr\\ \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c\,r^2}\frac{1}{b-a}[a<r<b]\,dr\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^b e^{-c\,r^2}\,dr\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_{-\infty}^b e^{-c\,r^2}\,dr\ -\ \int_{-\infty}^a e^{-c\,r^2}\,dr\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Now condider the definition of the standard normal CDF:
$$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\,dt.$$
Letting $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c}}\,t$, so $c\,r^2=\frac{1}{2}t^2$ and $dr=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c}}dt$, we have: 
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-c\,r^2}\,dr= \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2c}\,a}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c}}dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}\,\Phi(\sqrt{2c}\,a)
\end{align}$$
Substituting this, and the similar result involving $b$, into (1) gives the following:
$$\begin{align}E[e^{-c\,R^2}]=\frac{1}{b-a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}\bigg( \Phi(\sqrt{2c}\,b)\ -\ \Phi(\sqrt{2c}\,a)\bigg)\end{align}$$
Applying this formula to each of the expectations in your question will give the desired result. (Note that the factor of $\frac{\lambda_1}{2}$ is superfluous, as it appears on both sides of your equation.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Could you suggest a good reference material to understand this concept better?

Comment: @Abdulhameed The *expected value of a function of a random variable*, given the density function of that r.v., should be treated in most intro probability textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Abdulhameed BTW, you may like to know that the theorem being used here is sometimes jokingly called the ["law of the unconscious statistician"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).