# Proof for Cumulative distribution given an integral

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Proove this relation, given that $\phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal distribution.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2c}\,x}e^{\frac{-t^{2}}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2c}}dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}\Phi( \sqrt{2c}\,x)$$

A step-wise proof will be highly appreciated.

NB: This question is based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476107/expectation-with-a-variable-that-satisfies-uniform-distribution/2476217#2476217). Second to the last line on the extreme right.

The expression indicates the CDF of a continuous random variable X expressed as the integral of its probability density function

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}$ is not defined for $t<0$..

Comment: This is $\sqrt{2c}$ not $\sqrt{2t}$ in the denominator

Comment: @ Jimmy R. I have made the corrections. Thanks

Comment: I did two more corrections in your notation. First, it was $\Phi$ and not $\phi$ on the RHS (this is an important change) and second it was $\sqrt{2c}\,x$ instead of $\sqrt{2cx}$ (this is not important, I did it just to make it equal to your reference.). Ah, and the lower limit was $-\infty$ instead of $\infty$. I changed that too.

Comment: @ Jimmy R. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf $\phi(t)$ of the standard normal is $$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}, \quad \text{for } t\in \mathbb R$$ and the cdf $\Phi(x)$ is equal to $$\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(t)dt$$
Hence, in your case 
\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2c}\,a}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c}}dt&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{c}}\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2c}\,a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt&\\[0.2cm]&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2c}\,a}\phi(t)\,dt\\[0.2cm]&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}}\,\Phi(\sqrt{2c}\,a)\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. $\frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{\sqrt{\pi}}$ was multiplied with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ on the third line